# how to get account name in CosmosDB in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I wanna get the account name of cosmos DB.

[image]

But it seems that only the account endpoint is here.

```
const {CosmosClient} = require("@azure/cosmos");
const CONNECTION_STRING = process.env["CosmosDBConnectionString"];
const DATABASE_ID = process.env["CosmosDBDatabaseId"];

const client = new CosmosClient(CONNECTION_STRING);
const resource = (await client.getDatabaseAccount()).resource;

resource.readableLocations[0].databaseAccountEndpoint
//'https://xxxxxx-japaneast.documents.azure.com:443/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the endpoint, can't you use the JS method like below to obtain the account name?

```
const str = resource.readableLocations[0].databaseAccountEndpoint;
console.log(str.split('://').pop().split('.documents')[0]);
```